# How to move a child page in confluence using REST API

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I have a child page say CP1 listed under Parent page PP1. I need to move the child page CP1 to another Parent page say PP2. How can I achieve that using Confluence REST API?

I couldn't find any documentation related to moving a page in Confluence Docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out eventually. The solution is pretty simple. One merely needs to add this `"ancestors":[{"id":<id_of_the_parent_you_want_to_move_under>"}]` in the body of the PUT request.

I was also able to find the documentation for the same [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#content-update) which states that "To update a page and change its parent page, supply the ancestors property with the request with the parent as the first ancestor"

Summarizing, assuming you have the title of the page you wish to move, get the content Id and version of the page. Also get the contend Id of the parent you to wish to move the page under. This will be passed to ancestors id field. Then form a `PUT` request and pass the content Id, title, ancestors and version incremented by 1.

A sample `PUT` request:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: ..." -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1234567,"type":"page", "title":"Your page Title", "ancestors":[{"id":9876543}], "space":{"key":"xxx"},"version":{"number":17}}' "https://abc.def.domain.com/rest/api/content/1234567"
```

Comment: couldn't get it work, getting "You can't change an existing page's space" error.

Comment: Probably permissions issue. From https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/move-and-reorder-pages-146407727.html, `To move a page into a different space, you also need:
'Delete' permission on the space you're moving from, and 'Add' permission on the space you're moving to.`

Comment: I can move a page in same space, but can't get it work to move a page to a different space (Confluence 7.4.0), got  "You can't change an existing page's space" error. The account I am using is a admin account. Interestingly I tried Confluence CLI and it has movePage command, and it's using "/rpc/json-rpc/confluenceservice-v2/movePage"  call for some reason.

Comment: Hi @SandeepKanabar, do you know how to get the content Id?

Comment: @skyline - Hope this helps - https://confluence.som.yale.edu/display/SC/Finding+the+Page+ID+of+a+Confluence+Page